# Relation between fixed point and retraction theorem

Tags: category-theory

There is this particular exercise in Lawvere/Schanuels book "Conceptual Mathematics: A first introduction to categories" that I've worked on, but I'm not entirely sure if I'm correct. Plus, I'm a little confused with regards to certain elements.

**Question**:

"Let $j: C\to D$ be an inclusion map from circle C into disk D. Suppose that we have two continuous maps $f: D \to D$ and $g: D\to D$, and that g satisfies $g \circ j = j$. Use the retraction theorem to show that there must be a point x in the disk at which f(x) = g(x). (Hint: The fixed point theorem is the special case g = $1_D$, so try to generalize the argument we used in that special case.)"

**Attempted Answer**:

Knowing that there is an inclusion map j and a requirement of a retraction is needed, I first state the obvious

$r: D \to C$

which would create the identity $1_C$ when subject to $r \circ j$.

Since a retraction cannot co-exist with fixed points, the continuous maps f and g have to be:

$f(x) \neq x$ & $g(x) \neq x$ respectively.

Since g satisfies $g \circ j = j$, one can assume that since $g: D \to D$ is an endomap yielding $1_D$ implies $g = 1_D$. (Which apparently is a special case of the fixed point theorem? I assume due to the intermediate value theorem of a fixed point theorem it is such that for a given $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ there exists an $f(c)$ which yields $f(c)-c=0$ which is fine).

However, **by introducing a special case of the fixed point theorem, isnt it in violation of the rule that retractions cannot exist with fixed points?**

Disregarding the concern I have for the violation, proceeding with composition:

$r\circ g\circ j = r\circ f\circ j = r \circ j = 1_C$

As f and g are equivalent maps:

$g \circ j = f \circ j = 1_D \circ j = j$

Using Associativity laws and right hand identity, then left hand inverse:

$(r \circ g) = (r \circ f) = r$

$g = f = 1_D $

Hence there exists an identity map whereby f and g are equivalent and that the mapping yields x. But doesnt that mean that it is a contradiction, whereby $f(x) \neq x$, $g(x) \neq x$? Was this a trick question..? Because I certainly feel like 12 types of stupid right now.

EDIT: Additionally, it was mentioned thereafter in the textbook that each retraction theorem is equivalent to a fixed point theorem, that the fixed point theorem was deducible from the retraction theorem and vice versa.

I understand that the contrapositive statement exists, is that what is implied by the equivalence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you are studying on your own, and have not done a full introductory course in point set topology. There is a standard picture that you would probably have seen...

Assume that $f(x) \neq g(x)$ for every $x \in D.$ For every $x,$ draw the line segment that begins at $f(x),$ goes through $g(x),$ and continues on until some point on $C.$ Note that, when $x \in C,$ we already have $g(x) = x \in C,$ so the line segment stops at $x$ itself. Let us name $h(x)$ the point in $C$ where the line segment ends. There is a fair amount of justification needed for this step: $h$ is a continuous mapping. Since $h$ takes all of $D$ to $C$ and fixes $C$ pointwise, it is a retraction. However, we have found out that there is no retraction of the disk onto the circle. This contradicts the assumption that  $f(x) \neq g(x)$ for every $x \in D.$

Comment: I definitely have not started learning about point set topology and I do lack a great deal of mathematical maturity - I've just started purely on category theory and a long way to go. Ok, to wrap my idea around what you've said, the maps $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ do not connect except via line segment to substantiate the claim $f(x) \neq g(x)$. $g(x)=x$ will occur when x becomes an element of C, whereby $h(x)$, presumably will be a fixed point. $h(x)$ as apparent from the line segments D to C is negated, hence no fixed point, hence $g(x) \neq x$ and thus $f(x) = g(x)$?

Comment: @Cyrus, let me see if I can find a picture online somewhere.

Comment: Ouch, sounds like I didnt get it right. Thanks in advance for literally giving me a clearer picture.

Comment: @Cyrus, please see the picture on the right in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem#A_proof_using_homology  where their line segment starts at $f(x)$ and goes back through $x$ until the boundary circle is reached, and they call that point $F(x).$

Comment: @Cyrus, meanwhile, your summary above seems sort of correct, but i cannot really tell; it might be different if we were speaking in person. Rather late for me; I will chack this tomorrow to see if you had more to say.

Comment: I greatly appreciate you staying up late to address my queries. Looking upon the picture that you have sent, $g(x)$ in this sense would be along that line segment that isnt on the point x, this line segment would eventually land on $F(x)$, yielding $F(x) = x$ where in this case $F(x) = h(x)$ as previously mentioned. However, because $F(x)/h(x)$ cannot exist even though it is a retraction, it negates the rest of the supposition of $f(x) \neq g(x)$, the fixed point of $F(x)/h(x)$ and also $g(x)=x$ (when it belongs to C).

Answer (score 0):

```
However, by introducing a special case of the fixed point theorem, 
isn't it in violation of the rule that retractions cannot exist with fixed points?
```

Retractions and fixed points can coexist.  The book says there is no retraction between "boundary" and "disk", namely no $B^{n+1} \ to\ S^n$. This is not true for all $A \subset X$, namely there exists $A \subset X$ and A is a retract of X. In this case, if X has fixed point property then A has fixed point property. One can refer here for a brief proof. https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Fixed-point_property_is_retract-hereditary